# Mocking a class and an interface

Tags: java, unit-testing, interface, mockito

Hi all i have been trying so far to use mockito in my test.
Here is my questio: can i mock an interface so that every class that implements this interface will behave like described on mock?

This is the method i'm testing:

```
public static boolean initNewCluster(ServerConfiguration conf) throws Exception {
    return runFunctionWithRegistrationManager(conf, rm -> {
        try {
            return rm.initNewCluster();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("MOCK WORKS!!! \n");
            throw new UncheckedExecutionException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    });
}
```

And i would need to mock the call rm.initNewCluster().
Now this is the interface which has initNewCluster() as method:

```
@LimitedPrivate
@Evolving
public interface RegistrationManager extends AutoCloseable {

    

    /**
     * Initializes new cluster by creating required znodes for the cluster. If
     * ledgersrootpath is already existing then it will error out.
     *
     * @return returns true if new cluster is successfully created or false if it failed to initialize.
     * @throws Exception
     */

    boolean initNewCluster() throws Exception;
```

And here is the class which implements this interface:

```
    /**
     * ZooKeeper Based {@link RegistrationManager}.
     */
    @Slf4j
    public class ZKRegistrationManager implements RegistrationManager {
    
        private static final Function<Throwable, BKException> EXCEPTION_FUNC = cause -> {
            if (cause instanceof BKException) {
                log.error("Failed to get bookie list : ", cause);
                return (BKException) cause;
            } else if (cause instanceof InterruptedException) {
                log.error("Interrupted reading bookie list : ", cause);
                return new BKInterruptedException();
            } else {
                return new MetaStoreException();
            }
        };
    
        private final ServerConfiguration conf;
        private final ZooKeeper zk;
        private final List<ACL> zkAcls;
        private final LayoutManager layoutManager;
    
        private volatile boolean zkRegManagerInitialized = false;
    
        // ledgers root path
        private final String ledgersRootPath;
        // cookie path
        private final String cookiePath;
        // registration paths
        protected final String bookieRegistrationPath;
        protected final String bookieReadonlyRegistrationPath;
        // session timeout in milliseconds
        private final int zkTimeoutMs;
    
        public ZKRegistrationManager(ServerConfiguration conf,
                                     ZooKeeper zk,
                                     RegistrationListener listener) {
            this(conf, zk, ZKMetadataDriverBase.resolveZkLedgersRootPath(conf), listener);
        }
    
        public ZKRegistrationManager(ServerConfiguration conf,
                                     ZooKeeper zk,
                                     String ledgersRootPath,
                                     RegistrationListener listener) {
            this.conf = conf;
            this.zk = zk;
            this.zkAcls = ZkUtils.getACLs(conf);
            this.ledgersRootPath = ledgersRootPath;
            this.cookiePath = ledgersRootPath + "/" + COOKIE_NODE;
            this.bookieRegistrationPath = ledgersRootPath + "/" + AVAILABLE_NODE;
            this.bookieReadonlyRegistrationPath = this.bookieRegistrationPath + "/" + READONLY;
            this.zkTimeoutMs = conf.getZkTimeout();
    
            this.layoutManager = new ZkLayoutManager(
                zk,
                ledgersRootPath,
                zkAcls);
    
            this.zk.register(event -> {
                if (!zkRegManagerInitialized) {
                    // do nothing until first registration
                    return;
                }
                // Check for expired connection.
                if (event.getType().equals(EventType.None)
                    && event.getState().equals(KeeperState.Expired)) {
                    listener.onRegistrationExpired();
                }
            });
        }
    
.
.
.
.
.
.
    
    
       
    
        @Override
        public boolean initNewCluster() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("I have been called ! \n");
            String zkServers = ZKMetadataDriverBase.resolveZkServers(conf);
            String instanceIdPath = ledgersRootPath + "/" + INSTANCEID;
            log.info("Initializing ZooKeeper metadata for new cluster, ZKServers: {} ledger root path: {}", zkServers,
                    ledgersRootPath);
    
            boolean ledgerRootExists = null != zk.exists(ledgersRootPath, false);
    
            if (ledgerRootExists) {
                log.error("Ledger root path: {} already exists", ledgersRootPath);
                return false;
            }
    
            List<Op> multiOps = Lists.newArrayListWithExpectedSize(4);
    
            // Create ledgers root node
            multiOps.add(Op.create(ledgersRootPath, EMPTY_BYTE_ARRAY, zkAcls, CreateMode.PERSISTENT));
    
            // create available bookies node
            multiOps.add(Op.create(bookieRegistrationPath, EMPTY_BYTE_ARRAY, zkAcls, CreateMode.PERSISTENT));
    
            // create readonly bookies node
            multiOps.add(Op.create(
                bookieReadonlyRegistrationPath,
                EMPTY_BYTE_ARRAY,
                zkAcls,
                CreateMode.PERSISTENT));
    
            // create INSTANCEID
            String instanceId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            multiOps.add(Op.create(instanceIdPath, instanceId.getBytes(UTF_8),
                    zkAcls, CreateMode.PERSISTENT));
    
            // execute the multi ops
            zk.multi(multiOps);
    
            // creates the new layout and stores in zookeeper
            AbstractZkLedgerManagerFactory.newLedgerManagerFactory(conf, layoutManager);
    
            log.info("Successfully initiated cluster. ZKServers: {} ledger root path: {} instanceId: {}", zkServers,
                    ledgersRootPath, instanceId);
            return true;
        }
    
        
    }
```

Here's my test class :

```
package org.apache.bookkeeper.client;


import org.apache.bookkeeper.conf.ServerConfiguration;
import org.apache.bookkeeper.discover.RegistrationManager;
import org.apache.bookkeeper.discover.ZKRegistrationManager;
import org.apache.bookkeeper.meta.LayoutManager;
import org.apache.bookkeeper.test.BookKeeperClusterTestCase;
import org.apache.bookkeeper.test.ZooKeeperCluster;
import org.apache.bookkeeper.test.ZooKeeperUtil;
import org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper;
import org.apache.zookeeper.data.ACL;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;



import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;


@RunWith(value= Parameterized.class)
public class BookKeeperAdminInitNewClusterTest extends BookKeeperClusterTestCase {

    private boolean result;
    private ServerConfiguration conf;
    private String confType ;

    private static final int numOfBookies = 2;
    private final int lostBookieRecoveryDelayInitValue = 1800;


    @Mock
    RegistrationManager mockedRM = mock(RegistrationManager.class) ;
  


    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> getTestParameters(){
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{

                //last parameter states if the method rm.initNewCluster() called inside
                // BookKeeperAdmin.initNewCluster(conf) must be mocked or not

                //{true ,  "new" },
                //{false , "null" },
                //{false , "wrong"},
                {false , "mock"},  //caso di test introdotto per portare la branch coverage al 100%
                                    // entrando nella clausola catch del metodo initNewCluste()

        });

    }



    public BookKeeperAdminInitNewClusterTest(boolean result , String conf) throws Exception {

        super(numOfBookies, 480);
        baseConf.setLostBookieRecoveryDelay(lostBookieRecoveryDelayInitValue);
        baseConf.setOpenLedgerRereplicationGracePeriod(String.valueOf(30000));
        setAutoRecoveryEnabled(true);

        this.result = result;
        this.confType = conf;


    }

    @Test
    public void testInitNewCluster() throws Exception {

        boolean realResult ;


        if(confType == "null"){

            this.conf = null;

        }else if( confType == "wrong"){

            this.conf = new ServerConfiguration().setMetadataServiceUri("zk+hierarchical://127.0.0.1/ledgers");

        }else if(confType == "new") {

            this.conf = new ServerConfiguration(baseConf);
            String ledgersRootPath = "/testledgers";
            this.conf.setMetadataServiceUri(newMetadataServiceUri(ledgersRootPath));

        }else if(confType == "mock"){



            this.conf = new ServerConfiguration(baseConf);
            String ledgersRootPath = "/testledgers";
            this.conf.setMetadataServiceUri(newMetadataServiceUri(ledgersRootPath));
   

            when(mockedRM.initNewCluster()).thenThrow(new Exception());



        }


        try {

            realResult = BookKeeperAdmin.initNewCluster(conf);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            realResult = false ;
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        assertEquals(result,realResult);
    }

}`
```

The problem is when BookKeeperAdmin.initNewCluster(conf) gets called it leads to the call of the implementation method initNewCluster() and not to the one i have mocked!
Hope you can help, good day everyone!

Comment: You have two `initNewCluster()` methods in your example code; the other one is `static` (in `BookkeeperAdmin`) meaning you cannot mock it with "traditional' mocking (without bytecode manipulation). Could you clarify what you're trying to test exactly?

Comment: Who wrote this code made a unhappy choice of names imo so i recap the situation to clarify a bit: i have 3 methods called initNewCluster : the first one is from the class BookkeeperAdmin and it's the method i am testing.Let's call it methodA. The other 2 methods initNewCluster are from the interface RegistrationManager and it's implementation ZKmanager or something.Let's call this 2 methods respectively methodB and methodBImplementation. Problem is that methodA in his execution calls methodB.I mocked methodB but instead of rising an exception as i expected methodBImplementation gets executed.

Comment: I don't know if i was more clear... the point is i am not trying to mock BookkeeperAdmin.initNewCluster() but the method rm.initNewCluster() (they have same name but are different methods) which is called inside the first one so that this second method can raise an exception and get me inside the catch block of the first snippet of code i posted

Comment: Can you add the source code of `BookKeeperAdmin` also?

Comment: It's a long code so i add here the link to code inside my public repo to that class : https://github.com/CecBazinga/bookkeeper/blob/master/bookkeeper-server/src/main/java/org/apache/bookkeeper/client/BookKeeperAdmin.java